# C++ inet_ntoa causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, unix, g++

inet_ntoa() function causes Segmentation fault error in the following code. Tell me, why, please. And how do I fix it? Thanks a lot!

```
void ClientAdd ( int clientSocket )
{
    sockaddr            clientAddress;
    socklen_t           clientAddressLength;
    sockaddr_in*        clientAddressInternet;
    char*               clientHost;

    getpeername ( clientSocket , &clientAddress , &clientAddressLength );
    clientAddressInternet = (struct sockaddr_in*)&clientAddress;
    clientHost = inet_ntoa ( clientAddressInternet->sin_addr );
};
```

I think it's all about return value of inet_ntoa. But I don't know how how to find out...

PS compiling with g++@debian

Comment: Is that your real code? Or have you left bits out? You have real problems if that is the real code.

Comment: I've updated the code. Could you please be more kinda concrete?

Comment: It's clear you don't understand pointers. You cannot use pointers like `clientAddress` and `clientAddressLength` like that. Pointers have to point somewhere. `getpeername` expects pointers that point at something, not the uninitialised pointers you have given it. I'm not an expert on socket programming but something like this would be better. `sockaddr clientAddress; socklen_t clientAddressLength; getpeername ( clientSocket , &clientAddress , &clientAddressLength );`. You see this way I've passed pointers *that actually point to something* to `getpeername`.

Comment: Well, there are a load of pointers that don't seem to point to anything?  Seems like you need less '*' and more '&', either that or some mallocs.

Comment: Latest edit looks much better. Is it working now? You could still drop the casts though, they don't add anything. Just `getpeername ( clientSocket , &clientAddress , &clientAddressLength );` is better still.

Comment: @jahhaj thanks a lot, I've edited the code and it works well now. And I really have some kinda misunderstanding of pointers..

Comment: @Kolyunya: They do take a bit of getting used to. The mistake you made is fairly common. And you fixed up the rest of the code very well.

Comment: And still can not understand one idea. How does the return value of inet_ntoa fit a char* variable? I mean it returns a number of chars, or?

Comment: @Kolyunya: As I said I'm not an expert in sockets programming. So I looked this function up, and this is what I read 'inet_ntoa() returns the dots-and-numbers string in a static buffer that is overwritten with each call to the function.' So there is a single pre-allocated area used by this function every time it is called. The pointer you get back is just a pointer to that area. What this means of course is that if you call `inet_ntoa` again you will overwrite the value that was put into this area by the previous call. Pointers are tricky.

Comment: @jahhaj thanks a lot for your explanation, mate. Do I understand you correctly, that  inet_ntoa() returns just an address of some memory area. And if i call inet_ntoa() the 2nd time, the 2nd new pointer will point to the very same address, but this address will contain NEW data, right?
Thanks a lot again and maybe, you will post some kind of "answer" below, so I can mark the question solved and pass you some points :)

Comment: Yes. Quoting the man page (at least the version on my Ubuntu system): "The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite."

Comment: @Kolyunya: Answer below. And just to back up what Keith said, your understanding of `inet_ntoa` is right. Because of this 'quaint' interface it would be safer to copy the returned IP address so that a later call doesn't overwrite the value you have. The simplest way to do that would be to use the C++ string class instead of a char*. `std::string clientHost; clientHost = inet_ntoa ( clientAddressInternet->sin_addr );` The string class will make the copy for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getpeername` expects to be passed two pointers pointing to memory where it can write the client address and client address length. So your original code

```
sockaddr*            clientAddress;
socklen_t*           clientAddressLength;

getpeername ( clientSocket , clientAddress , clientAddressLength );
```

is wrong because the two pointers `clientAddress` and `clientAddressLength` are uninitialised. These pointers will be pointing at some arbitrary location in memory and writing to them is liable to crash the program, if not immediately then shortly afterwards. The simplest way to call `getpeername` correctly is to declare two variables, instead of two pointers, and then use the address-of operator '&' to pass the address of these variables to `getpeername`. Like this

```
sockaddr            clientAddress;
socklen_t           clientAddressLength;

getpeername ( clientSocket , &clientAddress , &clientAddressLength );
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help, jahhaj! I'd like to up vote you, but I don't have the privilege yet...